# Why are numpy operations faster than a custom openMP shared library

Tags: c++, numpy, openmp, vectorization, .so

the objective of the code was to compare execution times of numpy vs that of calling libtest.so with openMP parallelism. The objective is to take 2 arrays and array_2 = array1*2.0.
surprisingly numpy is way-way faster. time for numpy is `0.08785637099999999` whereas the testlib.so takes `1.087072129`.
The C++ code is as follows -

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <omp.h>
extern "C"
{
  void cfun(const double *indatav, size_t size, double *outdatav)  
  {
  #pragma omp parallel for simd
  for(size_t i =0;i<size;i++)
  outdatav[i] = indatav[i]*2.0;
  }
}
```

and the python code is as follows -

```
import types
import time
import numpy

from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libtest.so')

fun = lib.cfun
fun.restype = None
fun.argtypes = [ndpointer(ctypes.c_double, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),
            ctypes.c_size_t,
            ndpointer(ctypes.c_double, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS")]

indata = numpy.ones((10000, 10000))
outdata = numpy.empty((10000, 10000))

s = time.process_time()
outdata = indata*2.0
e = time.process_time()

print(e-s)

s = time.process_time()
fun(indata, indata.size, outdata)
e = time.process_time()

print(e-s)
```

Could anyone please explain why could this be happening and Is there any way I could make the library method faster<\br>
Thanks in Advance<\br>
Note- I am running gcc-8.3, an intel -i7 9750H, 6C/12T

Comment: For starters: did you compile your C++ code with optimizations enabled?

Comment: Did you compile with compiler optimizations enabled? If not, do that.

Comment: Overhead of starting the thread team is the obvious one: you don't have enough work to make the parallelism pay off its costs.

Comment: I dont think omp pragma directives require explicit compilation time directives. I quite new to this so please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: This is the max array size I can afford. I increase the size 100 times(adding a zero to each dimension) and I get the traceback saying cannot allot 74.5 GB with dtype float64

Comment: On the contrary, OpenMP pragmas require some very specific compile time options, otherwise they are simply ignored. It's `-fopenmp` for GCC and Clang to enable OpenMP in general and `-fopenmp-simd` to enable the SIMD-related parts.

Comment: When you cite execution times and ask why they have the values observed, it only makes sense if you also bother to tell us what CPU you have, how many threads you run the code with, how fast the memory is, what compilers you use, what compile options you used, etc.

Comment: I did use -fopenmp during compilation, otherwise it would not have compiled. I did not know about -simd part.. Will try that out and report  back, nothing for parallel regions though right ?

Comment: Also, consider the fact that you are measuring the wrong time. `time.process_time()` returns the total CPU time for all threads. It is a **very natural thing** that a parallel program with have higher process CPU time than a non-parallel one. Use the wall-clock timer!

Comment: Sorry about that, I will add the details In the question

Comment: using -fopenmp-simd did wonders, brought down the time to 0.228..Using time.time() and time.process_time() give the same value of time elapsed

Comment: Thanks a lot @HristoIliev, you have been a lot of help

Comment: on a side note, numpy uses blas and lapack under the hood

Comment: If you are getting the same results from using `time.time()` and `time.process_time()`, especially if that is also the case when you vary the array size, then the program is **not** running in parallel.

Comment: Changed the array shape (10000, 100000) and the times change, libtest.so runs much faster now

Comment: @AtharvaDubey Can you summarize this in an answer?

Comment: Your timings are a bit misleading. In the C-version you measure only the calculation time, in the Numpy version you are measuring memory allocation+ calculation time (the memory allocation usually takes longer than the calculation). If you use `numpy.multiply(indata, 2.,out=outdata)` it is comparable and both should be equally fast. By comparing the timings to `numpy.copyto(outdata,indata)` you should see, that this calculation is memory bandwidth limited.